# how to add a textbox to a powerpoint presentation using vba

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint

I'm writing a macro which creates a powerpoint presentation and then copys data from a spreadsheet and adds a title and a textbox. I've been able to add the data and tile and format both however I'm struggling to add a textbox. When I run the code below it returns the error 'ActiveX component can't create object'. I feel like over looking something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Error occurs on the line after the first set of '-------')

```
Sub Create_Presentation()

Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim myShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim myTextbox As Shape


On Error Resume Next


  Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

  Err.Clear

  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")


  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True


  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

Set rng = Range("PL_Tot")
rng.Copy

  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=xlBitmap
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)


  myShape.Left = 0.3
  myShape.Top = 67

  myShape.Width = 430
  myShape.Height = 406.4

mySlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Range("TotalTitle").Value

Set sldTitle = mySlide.Shapes.Title

With sldTitle
With .TextFrame.TextRange
With .Font
.Bold = msoTrue
.Size = 22
.Color = RGB(0, 0, 200)
End With
End With
End With

sldTitle.Top = -30
'------------------------------------

Set myPresentation = ActivePresentation

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(1)

Set myTextbox = mySlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=0, Top:=10, Width:=200, Height:=50)

With myTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = Range("PPTextbox").Value
    With .Font
        .Size = 12
        .Name = "Arial"
    End With
End With

'-----------------------------------
 PowerPointApp.Visible = True
 PowerPointApp.Activate


 Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Here is a simple example of adding a stickynote-style textbox to PowerPoint via macro: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58205047/470749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel and PowerPoint can both have Shape objects. Your:

```
Dim myTextbox As Shape
```

prepares Excel to expect an Excel shape.  Change it to

```
Dim myTextbox As PowerPoint.Shape
```

so Excel doesn't bark when you try to apply PowerPoint properties and methods to an Excel shape.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now. New it was going to be something simple.